# Magento 2 for logged In customer need to add shipping address every time i place a new order?

Tags: api, rest-api, shipping-address

> **This is what i am following...**

**1. Add Configurable product in cart.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/items
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "HKrh15hc", <product SKU>
    "qty": 5,
    "quote_id": "75", <Quote ID - Cart ID>
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "configurable_item_options": [
          {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": 49
          },
          {
            "option_id": "141",
            "option_value": 168
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

> Now, this is saving my configurable product in my cart.

---

**2. Get & put Shipping Information.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "addressInformation": {
        "shippingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "400001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH",
            "sameAsBilling": 1
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "221,Baker-street (e)"
            ],
            "company": "Lumos",
            "telephone": "12345678",
            "postcode": "4000001",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Aditya",
            "lastname": "Shah",
            "email": "Aditya@Shah.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH"
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
    }
}
```

---

- **Now, this 2nd STEP - Do i need to add shipping and Billing address every-time ?**
- **Whenever i place a new order with the same customer ?**

**3. Get payment method.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/75/payment-methods
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`

---

**4. Place an order.**

```
http://magento-host/index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
```

- `method : POST`
- `Authorization : Bearer <customer token>`
- `body data : json`

---

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "checkmo"
    }
}
```

**Concern**

---

**IN Step -2**

> **1. Do i need to add address (Billing and Shipping) every-time to place
>       an order ?**
>
> **2. Is there any thing like pass the `address_id` or default address -
>    so i don't need to add
>       addresses every-time.**

Comment: when you set the use as default shipping/billing address for customer it does not automatically use those addresses in the api?

Comment: No it doesn't -REST API is not fetching  defaultShipping address value.

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: Yes I got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Magento 2 have API - which we can select from existing address from customer account addresses API, so
>   customer don't need to add address every time whenever he/she places a
>   new order.

**quoteShippingMethodManagementV1**

Interface `ShippingMethodManagementInterface`

```
POST /V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id
```

**Data**

```
{
  "addressId": 0
}
```